# Implementing a REST API in a Clean Architecture

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture, rest, spring-mvc

I have been implementing a proof of concept application using Uncle Bob's Clean Architecture and I have run into a bit of a problem.

Uncle Bob's architecture calls for the explicit separation of request and responses using interfaces. This is not a problem in most cases (e.g. when implementing a UI using the MVP pattern) but I don't know how to apply this to create a REST API using Spring MVC.

My `Controller` has a method with the following signature:

```
Response<String> greet(String name)
```

mapped to `/greeting` that takes a name and outputs a different greeting depending on the value of the name.

Injected into the `Controller` is the `UseCase` that receives the name and creates the greeting, sending the output through the `OutputPort` injected into it.

The problem is that I cannot separate the inputs and outputs in this way because the `Controller` needs to interact with both the inputs and outputs to create a response.

The only way to "implement" this, that I can come up with, is returning the value using the `InputPort`, which sounds pretty bad and not at all what a Clean Architecture calls for.

I've been thinking about this and I cannot find any way that my `Controller` can act both as a `Controller` and as a `Presenter` at the same time. Am I missing something here? Is there a better desing that would allow the separation of the inputs and outputs of the REST API without massively overcomplicating things?

EDIT: I have been reading again chapters 23 and 24 of Clean Architecture and I sure could have phrased my questions a lot better.
What I have right now as a (working, perfectly fine) solution is a One-Dimensional Boundary (page 219) and I was wondering if I could extend this and separate this interface into two reciprocal interfaces. Hopefully this clarifies my point a bit.

Comment: Does your controller do much more than passing calls to your underlying "businesses" model or service?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti No, it shouldn't have any logic other than, maybe, convert the response object to a REST friendly format (JSON or the like).

Comment: Then IMHO forgot about "clean" under-explained, opinionated, unnecessary, redundant "architectures" and you already have a clean separation between your layers. Your controller here is your interface adapter (if you want to call it this way) and that's all you ever need. Anyway, even with my hostility against "clean" buzzword I think you're following its principles.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Yes, this is something of a minor problem, because the separation is clearly there. Although, that being said, it was still rubbing me the wrong way having to change the interfaces to add a return value to an **input** port.

Comment: @Carlos, I strongly suspect that you are misunderstanding, or misapplying, the architectural constraints that Uncle Bob is recommending.  But it's difficult to untangle without reference the specific guidance that you think applies.  You might improve the question with quotations or links to the guidance that is giving you trouble.

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason I've edited my question a bit, to try and make my point clearer. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Oh!  You are trying to figure out how to make Figure 22.2 work?

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason Pretty much, yeah. In the context of a method that needs to call the input boundary and receive the answer from the output boundary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I think I see what's going on: you've got a context impedance mismatch.

> You're in a framework now, Mr. Bond.  The game with the composition is played a little bit differently here.

The basic idea to recognize is this: the "View", so to speak, changes with every HTTP request that arrives (more precisely, it has a scope coupled to the lifetime of the HTTP *Connection*, but that's not important here).

That means that we need to [compose](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) a new `Controller->Use-Case-Interactor->Presenter` pipeline for each request.

The good news: Spring is already doing that for you under the covers.

The bad news: Spring is using a single Input-Output boundary, rather than separating them.

I say "bad news" because you are trying to make this round peg fit into the square hole described by Martin.  I think what Spring is doing here is "fine", it's just inconvenient for the interfaces you want.

So let's pretend: you have a use-case-interactor that expects to be wired to an input boundary and an output boundary, and you have this signature on your controller.  Now what?

```
Response<String> greet(String name) {
    InputBoundary in = inputBoundaryFor(name);

    // Arbitrary choice
    List<String> greetings = new ArrayList();
    OutputBoundary out = outputBoundaryFor(greetings);

    // Here's our composition with request scope.
    UseCaseInteractor uci = useCaseInteractorFor(in, out);

    uci.run();

    String greeting = greetings.get(0);

    return responseFrom(greetings.get(0));
}
```

If you were a bit luckier with the API for your UseCaseInteractor, it might instead look like:

```
final UseCaseInteractor uci = ...

Response<String> greet(String name) {
    InputBoundary in = inputBoundaryFor(name);

    // Arbitrary choice - any reasonable container for
    // for a result could be used here.
    CompleteableFuture<String> greetings = new ArrayList();
    OutputBoundary out = outputBoundaryFor(greetings);

    uci.run(in, out);

    String greeting = greetings.get();

    return responseFrom(greetings.get(0));
}
```

You might find this more familiar if we were to structure it as a callback

```
Response<String> greet(String name) {
    // Arbitrary choice - any reasonable container for
    // for a result could be used here.
    CompleteableFuture<String> greetings = new ArrayList();

    uci.run(name, (greeting) -> {
        greetings.complete(greeting);
    });

    String greeting = greetings.get();

    return responseFrom(greetings.get(0));
}
```

The core idea, though, is that you have two functions; in the module with your use case interactor, you have a function that looks like

```
InputData -> OutputData
```

and in your web layer, you have a function that looks like

```
OutputData -> ViewModel
```

the input and output boundaries are just *a* way to compose those two functions *without introducing a dependency that points the wrong way*.

Comment: I believe the example here would have been much more expressive if we had a return type (and parameter type) other than `String`. A *dependency that points the wrong way* would be the `UseCaseInteractor` depending on the **Controller's param/return type**. So this is the reason we use `InputBound` and `OutputBound` to **convert** these objects to/from the **domain model** recognized by the `UseCaseInteractor` and **inverse the dependency**.